# usbip error open vhci driver

Tags: kernel, usb

UPDATED (see below)
After installing the usbip package on client and server, loading the kernel modules on both, I started usbipd on the server:

```
sudo usbipd
usbipd: info: starting usbipd (usbip-utils 2.0)EDIT: I found better instructions here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/tools/usb/usbip
```

client:
sudo modprobe vhci-hcd
sudo usbip attach -r 192.168.5.153 -b 1-1

server:

usbipd: info: connection from 192.168.1.2:40942
usbipd: info: received request: 0x8003(4)
usbipd: info: found requested device: 1-1
usbip: info: connect: 1-1
usbipd: info: request 0x8003(4): complete

client:

sudo lsusb
(the expected usb device is not shown and also KDE multimedia tools do not show any new audio devices)
    usbipd: info: listening on 0.0.0.0:3240
    usbipd: error: socket: :::3240: 97 (Address family not supported by protocol)

I did not look into the above error, and I do not know if it is relevant but I am assuming it is not.

Then I bound my usb device:

```
sudo usbip bind -b 1-1
```

Then on the client I attached the device:

```
sudo usbip attach -r 192.168.1.153 -b 1-1
libusbip: error: udev_device_new_from_subsystem_sysname failed
usbip: error: open vhci_driver
```

The following messages were shown on the server for usbipd (I tried to connect twice):

```
usbipd: info: connection from 192.168.1.2:40910
usbipd: info: received request: 0x8005(4)
usbipd: info: exportable devices: 1
usbipd: info: request 0x8005(4): complete
usbipd: info: connection from 192.168.1.2:40912
usbipd: info: received request: 0x8003(4)
usbipd: info: found requested device: 1-1
usbip: info: connect: 1-1
usbipd: info: request 0x8003(4): complete
usbipd: info: connection from 192.168.1.2:40918
usbipd: info: received request: 0x8003(4)
usbipd: info: found requested device: 1-1
usbip: info: connect: 1-1
usbipd: info: request 0x8003(4): complete
```

`lsusb` shows that the client did not attach the usb device. The relevant errors on the client are:

```
libusbip: error: udev_device_new_from_subsystem_sysname failed
usbip: error: open vhci_driver
```

Both client and server are running these versions:

sudo pacman -Qi usbip
Name            : usbip
Version         : 4.18-1

Linux 4.18.6-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Sep 5 11:54:09 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I got installation help from here:
Tutorial – USB/IP » Linux Magazine http://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2018/208/Tutorial-USB-IP

UPDATE: I found better instructions here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/tools/usb/usbip

client:

```
sudo modprobe vhci-hcd
sudo usbip attach -r 192.168.5.153 -b 1-1
```

server:

```
usbipd: info: connection from 192.168.1.2:40942
usbipd: info: received request: 0x8003(4)
usbipd: info: found requested device: 1-1
usbip: info: connect: 1-1
usbipd: info: request 0x8003(4): complete
```

client:

```
sudo lsusb
```

(the expected usb device is not shown and also KDE multimedia tools do not show any new audio devices)

The journal on the client shows that the usb device is found but immediate unbound and it is not clear to me why.

```
# journalctl -r
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kernel: usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 4
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kernel: vhci_hcd: disconnect device
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kernel: vhci_hcd: release socket
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kernel: vhci_hcd: stop threads
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kernel: vhci_hcd: connection closed
Sep 23 05:12:20 client krunner[993]: [05::12:20.748] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client org_kde_powerdevil[1022]: [05::12:20.748] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kdeinit5[954]: [05::12:20.748] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kate[4517]: [05::12:20.748] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client plasmashell[995]: [05::12:20.748] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client baloo_file[991]: [05::12:20.748] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client systemsettings5[1170]: [05::12:20.748] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kdeinit5[954]: [05::12:20.748] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kdeinit5[954]: [05::12:20.748] unknown: QObject::connect: invalid null parameter
Sep 23 05:12:20 client org_kde_powerdevil[1022]: [05::12:20.748] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client krunner[993]: [05::12:20.748] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client plasmashell[995]: [05::12:20.747] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kate[4517]: [05::12:20.747] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client systemsettings5[1170]: [05::12:20.747] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client baloo_file[991]: [05::12:20.747] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kdeinit5[954]: [05::12:20.747] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kdeinit5[954]: [05::12:20.747] unknown: QObject::connect: invalid null parameter
Sep 23 05:12:20 client baloo_file[991]: [05::12:20.747] unknown: QObject::connect: invalid null parameter
Sep 23 05:12:20 client baloo_file[991]: [05::12:20.746] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client org_kde_powerdevil[1022]: [05::12:20.746] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client plasmashell[995]: [05::12:20.746] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client systemsettings5[1170]: [05::12:20.746] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client krunner[993]: [05::12:20.746] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kate[4517]: [05::12:20.746] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kdeinit5[954]: [05::12:20.746] unknown: QObject::connect: invalid null parameter
Sep 23 05:12:20 client baloo_file[991]: [05::12:20.746] unknown: QObject::connect: invalid null parameter
Sep 23 05:12:20 client baloo_file[991]: [05::12:20.745] unknown: QObject::connect: invalid null parameter
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kdeinit5[954]: [05::12:20.744] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client baloo_file[991]: [05::12:20.744] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client systemsettings5[1170]: [05::12:20.744] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client org_kde_powerdevil[1022]: [05::12:20.744] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kdeinit5[954]: [05::12:20.744] unknown: QObject::connect: invalid null parameter
Sep 23 05:12:20 client krunner[993]: [05::12:20.744] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client plasmashell[995]: [05::12:20.744] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kate[4517]: [05::12:20.744] unknown: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client baloo_file[991]: [05::12:20.743] unknown: QObject::connect: invalid null parameter
Sep 23 05:12:20 client mtp-probe[5684]: bus: 3, device: 4 was not an MTP device
Sep 23 05:12:20 client mtp-probe[5684]: checking bus 3, device 4: "/sys/devices/platform/vhci_hcd.0/usb3/3-1"
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kernel: hid-generic 0003:0746:3000.0003: hidraw0: USB HID v1.00 Device [ONKYO USB HS Audio Device] on usb-vhci_hcd.0-1/input2
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kernel: hid-generic 0003:0746:3000.0003: No inputs registered, leaving
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kernel: usb 3-1: Manufacturer: ONKYO
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kernel: usb 3-1: Product: USB HS Audio Device
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kernel: usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kernel: usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0746, idProduct=3000, bcdDevice=22.04
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kernel: usb 3-1: SetAddress Request (4) to port 0
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kernel: usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using vhci_hcd
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kernel: vhci_hcd vhci_hcd.0: devid(65544) speed(3) speed_str(high-speed)
Sep 23 05:12:20 client kernel: vhci_hcd vhci_hcd.0: pdev(0) rhport(0) sockfd(3)
Sep 23 05:10:53 client nm-dispatcher[5670]: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [wlan0]: completed: no scripts
Sep 23 05:10:53 client nm-dispatcher[5670]: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [wlan0]: new request (0 scripts)
Sep 23 05:10:53 client systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Sep 23 05:10:53 client dbus-daemon[478]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Sep 23 05:10:53 client systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Sep 23 05:10:53 client dbus-daemon[478]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-disp>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime I've had that error it has been due to a **usbip-utils** version mismatch between the client and server. Check both by executing `usbip version` which should return something along the lines of `usbip (usbip-utils 2.0)`