# ubuntu 22.04, remote USB on Raspberry Pi 0 W

Tags: ubuntu

On my iMAC:

```
Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2015
4 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7
16 GB 1867 MHz DDR3
AMD Radeon R9 M395X 4 GB
```

I am running VirtualBox:

```
Version 7.0.14 r161095 (Qt5.15.2)
```

I have a Linux virtual machine:

```
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:     22.04
Codename:    jammy
```

I connect to a Raspberry Pi 0 W which has an IP on my network of 192.168.5.185, I have enabled root and ssh, connected to the Raspberry Pi I have a CAN-BUS USB device, from ssh terminal:

```
root@RPi0:~# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1d50:606f OpenMoko, Inc. Geschwister Schneider CAN adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Using ssh I have enable the USB device:

```
root@RPi0:~# usbip list
 - busid 1-1 (1d50:606f)
   OpenMoko, Inc. : Geschwister Schneider CAN Adapter (1d50:606f)
```

The goal is to map the remote CAN BUS adapter to Ubuntu, which I have done before only a week ago, for another reason I had to start over and now I'm having a problem, when I try to list the remote usb devices from a Ubuntu terminal:

```
usbip list -r 192.168.5.185
usbip: info no exportable devices found on 192.168.5.185
```

I rebooted the Pi 0 and then in my Ubuntu terminal:

```
sy@Linux:~$ usbip list -r 192.168.5.185
Exportable USB devices
======================
 - 192.168.5.185
        1-1: OpenMoko, Inc. : Geschwister Schneider CAN adapter (1d50:606f)
           : /sys/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1
           : (Defined at Interface level) (00/00/00)

sy@Linux:~$ sudo usbip attach -r 192.168.5.185 -b 1-1
[sudo] password for sy:
libqsbip: error: udev_device_new_from_subsystem_sysname failed
usbip: error: open vhci_driver (is vhci_hcd loaded?)
```

I found this:
[usbip error open vhci driver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470827/usbip-error-open-vhci-driver)

I've checked the versions in ubuntu terminal and on remote:

```
sy@Linux: ~$ usbip version
usbip (usbip-utils 2.0)
sy@Linux: ~$ sudo ssh root@192.168.5.185
root:192.168.5.185's password:
Linux RPi0 6.1.21+ #1642 Mon Apr  3 17:19:14 BST 2023 armv6l

The programs included with Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the 
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.


Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last Login Sun Feb 25 11:26:32 2024 from 192.168.5.220
root@RPi0:~# usbip version
usbip (usbip-utils 2.0)
```

So both versions match, it isn't anything to do with the other stack-overflow reported message.

Interestingly if I kill the power on the Raspberry Pi, so the CAN Bus module comes up without being set-up and then I execute from Ubuntu as soon as I can ping the device:

```
usbip list -r 192.168.5.185
Exportable USB devices
======================
 - 192.168.5.185
        3-1: OpenMoko, Inc. : Geschwister Schneider CAN adapter (1d50:606f)
           : /sys/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1
           : (Defined at Interface level) (00/00/00)
```

Still get the same result:

```
sy@Linux:~$ sudo usbip attach -r 192.168.5.185 -b 3-1
[sudo] password for sy:
libqsbip: error: udev_device_new_from_subsystem_sysname failed
usbip: error: open vhci_driver (is vhci_hcd loaded?)
```

I then edited on the Pi /etc/modules and removed vhci_driver, the module is now back at 1-1, but same reported message:

```
sy@Linux:~$ sudo usbip attach -r 192.168.5.185 -b 1-1
[sudo] password for sy:
libqsbip: error: udev_device_new_from_subsystem_sysname failed
usbip: error: open vhci_driver (is vhci_hcd loaded?)
```

I think vhci_hcd should be loaded perhaps by Ubuntu?  How ?

---

On the Raspberry Pi 0 W I added:

```
sudo usbip bind —busid=X
```

Where X is the bus id assign to the USB device, which can be shown with:

```
usbip list -p -l
```

In my case it came up with:

```
busid=1-1#usbid=1d50:606f#
```

So X would be replaced with 1-1.  The only problem I have now is that with everything connected if I perform:

```
sudo reboot
```

The can0 device does not show up when I use:

```
ip link
```

I then have to disconnect the device by pulling the cable and reconnecting which is not acceptable.

Some information from dmesg:

```
[46.529564] IPv6 ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): can0: link becomes ready
[53.136367] usbip-host 1-1: usbip-host: register new device (bus 1 dev 2)
```

Can anyone help with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I reformatted the SD-Card again with Raspbian 11, I set-up the CAN module exactly as I did before, infact everything was set-up as before, the only difference is I did not try to run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

I'm convinced that the problem is caused by a buggy update.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading `vhci_hcd` driver? This helped in my case with the same error message:

```
sudo modprobe vhci_hcd
```